# Number unabbreviation function

Tags: javascript

I tried to make a function to unabbreviate numbers, it works fine, but it has some problems.

one is that the order of the string should be number and then letters (`1k`), and how I did the order doesn't matter.
according to it, it eliminates any character that is not a number or letter, this makes it possible to send the string in any way.

this is my code:

```js
const abbr = require('./numberAbbreviates.json');

function unabbreviate (number) {
    if(typeof number !== 'string') return new Error('Paramentro deve ser do tipo String.');
    let letters = number.replace(/[^A-z]/gi, '');
    number = Number(number.replace(/[^0-9.]/gi, ''));
    let unabbreviate = true
    if(!number) return 0;
    if(!abbr[letters]) unabbreviate = false
    return unabbreviate ? number * abbr[letters] : number
}
```

the content of `require('./numberAbbreviates.json')` is:

```json
{
  "K": 1e+3,
  "M": 1e+6,
  "B": 1e+9,
  "T": 1e+12,
  "Qa": 1e+15,
  "Qi": 1e+18,
  "Sx": 1e+21,
  "Sp": 1e+24,
  "O": 1e+27,
  "N": 1e+3,
  "D": 1e+33,
  "UD": 1e+36,
  "DD": 1e+39,
  "TD": 1e+42,
  "QaD": 1e+45,
  "QiD": 1e+48
...
```

`this goes until "UC": 1e+306`

Some examples of results:

```js
unnabbreviate('1.5k') // 1500
unnabreviate('1.55k') // 1550

// now some examples that shouldn't happen
unnabreviate('k1.5') // 1500
unnabreviate('@1.55@k') // 1550
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could more simply read character by character until you meet the first letter, this will be your number to convert, then you take all the left characters as the abbreviation text.
Even if the abbreviation text is wrong with numbers in between it doesn't matter since you will have a check like you have right now and return 0.

So the format will be Number+Abbreviation.

Edit: I'm from mobile I will be difficult for me to code the function :/